# Can I change the default branch that shows when I visit a github.com repository I don't own?

Tags: github

I'll use this repository as an example: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL

When I visit that URL, the repository's default branch is shown:

[image]

Is there a way to change this so that when I visit **that** URL, it shows me a different branch of my choosing? For example, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL shows this instead:

[image]

I know how to write a user script that would redirect from https://github.com/microsoft/WSL to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/tree/vhd-logs but I want to know if github.com has this functionality.

I also think I could fork this repo and change the default branch in my fork, but I'd like to avoid that.

---

Here's why want this functionality: one of the repos I frequent has a default branch and a branch meant for nightly/nightlies (sp?). When communicating with others, I often want to refer to a line of code in the nightly branch. It usually goes like this:

1. Open a new tab
2. Type in a portion of the repository name
3. Once it shows up in my history, visit that url
4. Change the branch I'm viewing `<-- I keep forgetting this step!`
5. Copy a link to the file/line I want to refer to in my discussion with others.

I forget step four so often, I just want to default the branch that comes up when I view this repository.

Now, *if* github doesn't have this feature, suggestions on a better workflow would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A bookmark in your browser?